# Python julian date format

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

I have a function in django that check for selected date and then convert that date to julian date then it extract data from the database based on the selected date.

but i am getting an error:

time data 'selected_date' does not match format '%Y-%M-%d'

my view.py

def sum_asset_fundmanager(request):

```
if "selectdate" in request.POST:
    selected_date = request.POST["selectdate"]
        if selected_date==selected_date:
        convert=datetime.datetime.strptime("selected_date", "%Y-%M-%d").toordinal()
        #calculating date MID Rate
        engine=create_engine('mssql+pymssql://username:password1@hostname /db')
        connection=engine.connect()
        metadata=MetaData()
        rate=Table('mccurtdt',metadata,autoload=True,autoload_with=engine)
        statmt=select([rate])

        statmt=statmt.where(and_(rate.columns.from_currency=='AUD',     rate.columns.rate_type=='MID',rate.columns.convert_date==convert))
        CORP101=connection.execute(statmt).fetchall()
```

return render(request,'template.html',locals())

my template.html

Select a Date:

{% csrf_token %}

Comment: You have `"selected_date"` in quotes, in the `strptime` call, so it's using that string and not the variable.

Comment: Thanks heaps. i didn't realize that.